# Modifying the values of an array of strucutres

Tags: c++, arrays

I am currently trying to model elastic collisions in c++. I have a structure called Particle which I am using to describe objects.

```
//Defining the particle structure
struct particle {
  double x;   // Position
  double p;   // Momentum
  double im;  // Inverse Mass
  double v;   // Velocity
  double T;   // Kinetic Energy
  double a;   // Radius of a Particle
};
```

I create an array of these structures using.

```
particle AP[n+2];
```

Part of my program needs to increment the position of each structure using a time variable and their velocity.

I am using this code

```
void LeapForward(struct particle AP[],double tfc,int n)
{
  for(int cycle=0; cycle<n+2; cycle++)
    {
      double second;
      second=AP[cycle].x+tfc*AP[cycle].v;
      AP[cycle].x=second;
    }
}
```

However, it appears that the array isnt being modified but instead recreated. I was wondering whether anyone knew why this was and if so how to fix this.

My full code can be found below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//This program will be about particle collsions 
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//Function for collision of particles
void Collision(struct particle AP[],int chosen);
void Assignment(struct particle AP[],int n);
void LeapForward(struct particle AP[], double tfc, int n);
void TimeForCollision(struct particle AP[],double tfc, int chosen, int n);

//Defining the particle structure
struct particle {
  double x;   // Position
  double p;   // Momentum
  double im;  // Inverse Mass
  double v;   // Velocity
  double T;   // Kinetic Energy
  double a;   // Radius of a Particle
};

//Variable Declaration
int n; //Number of particles
double tfc; //This is going to be the time to leap forward
int chosen; //Which particles are to collide

  //Main program 

  int main()
  {
    cout<<"How many particle do you want to model: ";
    cin>>n;
    particle AP[n+2];    

    //Assigning value to Particles
    Assignment(AP,n);    

    cout<<endl<<"Two walls have been placed at x=0 and 20"<<endl;
    //Assignment of Wall Data. 
    AP[0].im=0.000001,AP[n+1].im=0.000001;
    AP[0].x=0,AP[n+1].v=0;
    AP[0].x=0,AP[n+1].x=20;
    AP[0].a=0,AP[n+1].a=0;

  ofstream Port;
  Port.open ("Positions.txt");
    for(int model=0; model<2;model++)
      {
    //Time for next collision
    TimeForCollision(AP,tfc,chosen,n);
    LeapForward(AP,tfc,n);
    Collision(AP,chosen);
    for(int plot=0; plot<n+2;plot++)
      {
        Port<<AP[plot].x<<"\t";
          }
    Port<<endl;
      }
  }


void Collision(struct particle AP[],int chosen)
{
  double combinemass=1/AP[chosen].im+1/AP[chosen+1].im;
  double result1=(AP[chosen].v*(1/(AP[chosen].im)-1/(AP[chosen+1].im))+(2*AP[chosen+1].v*1/(AP[chosen+1].im)))/combinemass;
  double result2=(AP[chosen+1].v*(1/(AP[chosen+1].im)-1/(AP[chosen].im))+(2*AP[chosen].v*1/(AP[chosen].im)))/combinemass;
  AP[chosen].v=result1;
  AP[chosen+1].v=result2;
}

void Assignment(struct particle AP[],int n)
{
for(int cycle=1;cycle<=n;cycle++)
  {
    cout<<"Data Input for particle number "<<cycle<<endl;
    double mass;
    cout<<"What is the position of the particle : ";
    cin>>AP[cycle].x;
    cout<<"What is the mass of the particle : ";
    cin>>mass;
    AP[cycle].im=1/mass;
    cout<<"What is the velocity of the particle : ";
    cin>>AP[cycle].v;
    cout<<"What is the radius of the particle : ";
    cin>>AP[cycle].a;
    //Data calculation
    AP[cycle].p=AP[cycle].v*mass;
    AP[cycle].T=0.5*AP[cycle].v*mass*mass;
  }
}

void LeapForward(struct particle AP[],double tfc,int n)
{
  for(int cycle=0; cycle<n+2; cycle++)
    {
      double second;
      second=AP[cycle].x+tfc*AP[cycle].v;
      AP[cycle].x=second;
    }
}

void  TimeForCollision(struct particle AP[],double tfc, int chosen, int n)
{
 double balance=0;
 tfc=0;
  for(int cycle=0;cycle<n+1;cycle++)
    {
      double placeh=abs(((AP[cycle+1].x-AP[cycle+1].a)-(AP[cycle].x+AP[cycle].a)))/(AP[cycle].v-AP[cycle+1].v);
       if(placeh>tfc && placeh>0)
        {
      tfc=placeh;
      chosen=cycle;
        }
   }
   cout<<tfc<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Please do not change the code in your question to a version that works based on answers you have received. It invalidates your entire question.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious can you validatethat my answer is correct? I think that this is why his function is not modifying the values!

Comment: Sorry I am new to the site and didnt realise. My apologies.

Comment: However, I managed to solve my problem. SO if anyone reads this who is in a similar problem the only way to pass a array of unknown size is to use a pointer. A great website I found was http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-structures-pointers

Comment: @SiberianSloth That's exactly what I wrote in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you call your function, you will create a new instance of your struct and modify that newly created instance which will be deleted at the end of your function.

pass the value as a reference like this:

```
void LeapForward(struct particle *AP, double tfc, int n);
```

In addition, in your LeapForward function you don't need to create temporary double variable.
You can use something like:

```
AP[cycle].x += tfc * AP[cycle].v;
```

---

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/D2QSZe).